# How to calculate counts on pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have data something like this

```
import random
import pandas as pd

jobs = ['Agriculture', 'Crafts', 'Labor', 'Professional']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'JobCategory':[random.choice(jobs) for i in range(300)],
    'Region':[random.randint(1,5) for i in range(300)],
    'MaritalStatus':[random.choice(['Not Married', 'Married']) for i in range(300)]
})
```

And I want a simple table showing the count of jobs in each region.

```
print(pd.pivot_table(df,
           index='JobCategory',
           columns='Region',
           margins=True,
           aggfunc=len))
```

Output is

```
             MaritalStatus                               
Region                   1     2     3     4     5    All
JobCategory                                              
Agriculture           13.0  23.0  17.0  18.0   8.0   79.0
Crafts                16.0  13.0  18.0  19.0  14.0   80.0
Labor                 15.0  11.0  19.0  11.0  14.0   70.0
Professional          22.0  17.0  16.0   7.0   9.0   71.0
All                   66.0  64.0  70.0  55.0  45.0  300.0
```

I assume "MaritalStatus" is showing up in the output because that is the column that the count is being calculated on.  How do I get Pandas to calculate based on the Region-JobCategory count and ignore extraneous columns in the dataframe?

Added in edit ---

I am looking for a table with margin values to be output.  The values in the table I show are what I want but I don't want MaritalStatus to be what is counted.  If there is a Nan in that column, e.g. change the column definition to

```
'MaritalStatus':[random.choice(['Not Married', 'Married'])
                 for i in range(299)].append(np.NaN)
```

This is the output (both with and without `values = 'MaritalStatus',`)

```
             MaritalStatus                             
Region                   1     2     3     4     5  All
JobCategory                                            
Agriculture           16.0  14.0  16.0  14.0  16.0  NaN
Crafts                25.0  17.0  15.0  14.0  16.0  NaN
Labor                 14.0  16.0   8.0  17.0  15.0  NaN
Professional          13.0  14.0  14.0  13.0  13.0  NaN
All                    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fill the nan values with 0 and then find the len i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'JobCategory':[random.choice(jobs) for i in range(300)],
'Region':[random.randint(1,5) for i in range(300)],
'MaritalStatus':[random.choice(['Not Married', 'Married']) for i in range(299)].append(np.NaN)})

df = df.fillna(0)
print(pd.pivot_table(df,
       index='JobCategory',
       columns='Region',
       margins=True,
       values='MaritalStatus',
       aggfunc=len))
```

Output:

```
                          
Region                   1     2     3     4     5    All
JobCategory                                              
Agriculture           19.0  17.0  13.0  20.0   9.0   78.0
Crafts                17.0  14.0   9.0  11.0  16.0   67.0
Labor                 10.0  17.0  15.0  19.0  11.0   72.0
Professional          11.0  14.0  19.0  19.0  20.0   83.0
All                   57.0  62.0  56.0  69.0  56.0  300.0
```

Comment: No, I am looking for a table with margin values.

Comment: You can fill the Nan with some values and then find the len. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you cut the dataframe down to just the columns that are to be part of the final index counting rows works without having to refer to another column.

```
pd.pivot_table(testdata[['JobCategory', 'Region']],
               index='JobCategory',
               columns='Region',
               margins=True,
               aggfunc=len)
```

Output is the same as in the question except the line with "MaritialStatus" is not present.

Comment: amusing -- providing an answer of one's own but in the end accepting none

Answer (score 0):

The `len` aggregation function counts the number of times a value of `MaritalStatus` appears along a particular combination of `JobCategory - Region`. Thus you're counting the number of `JobCategory - Region` instances, which is what you're expecting I guess.

Comment: No, I'm counting the number of MaritalStatus instances in each combination.  This is problematic if the column has NaN's in it.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

We can assign key value to each records and count or size that value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'JobCategory':[random.choice(jobs) for i in range(300)],
'Region':[random.randint(1,5) for i in range(300)],
'MaritalStatus':[random.choice(['Not Married', 'Married']) for i in range(299)].append(np.NaN)})

print(pd.pivot_table(df.assign(key=1),
           index='JobCategory',
           columns='Region',
           margins=True,
           aggfunc=len,
           values='key'))
```

Output:

```
Region           1     2     3     4     5    All
JobCategory                                      
Agriculture   16.0  14.0  13.0  16.0  16.0   75.0
Crafts        14.0   9.0  17.0  22.0  13.0   75.0
Labor         11.0  18.0  20.0  10.0  16.0   75.0
Professional  16.0  14.0  15.0  14.0  16.0   75.0
All           57.0  55.0  65.0  62.0  61.0  300.0
```

---

You could add MaritalStatus as the `values` parameter, and this would eliminate that extra level in the column index.  With aggfunc=`len`, it really doesn't matter what you select as the values parameter it is going to return a count of 1 for every row in that aggregation.

So, try:

```
print(pd.pivot_table(df,
           index='JobCategory',
           columns='Region',
           margins=True,
           aggfunc=len,
           values='MaritalStatus'))
```

Output:

```
Region           1     2     3     4     5    All
JobCategory                                      
Agriculture   10.0  18.0  10.0  15.0  19.0   72.0
Crafts        11.0  13.0  17.0  11.0  22.0   74.0
Labor         12.0  10.0  18.0  16.0  12.0   68.0
Professional  21.0  16.0  20.0  13.0  16.0   86.0
All           54.0  57.0  65.0  55.0  69.0  300.0
```

## Option 2

Use `groupby` and `size`:

```
df.groupby(['JobCategory','Region']).size()
```

Output:

```
JobCategory   Region
Agriculture   1         10
              2         18
              3         10
              4         15
              5         19
Crafts        1         11
              2         13
              3         17
              4         11
              5         22
Labor         1         12
              2         10
              3         18
              4         16
              5         12
Professional  1         21
              2         16
              3         20
              4         13
              5         16
dtype: int64
```

Comment: In the pivot_table example, If the extra column I use contains a NaN then all the margin values are NaN.  The groupby doesn't give values for 'All' and would have to be munged into table form.

Comment: Create that example in your problem.  And if you don't want to aggregate NaN values, look at the difference between size and len vs count.  Count only counts non-null values.

Comment: @verisimilidude Okay. see edit, where I create a 'key' column with a value of one for every records, then I count that column for my aggregation.